# Annoying assembly codes in Delphi XE4 after method calls

Tags: delphi, debugging, assembly

What option should I check out to disable the assembly code tracing after every method call in Delphi XE4?

If you trace (F7) the call of TMyClass.foo, the set of the result cause an assembly tracing.

```
type
  TMyClass = class
    public
      function foo : string;
  end;

function TMyClass.foo : string;
begin
  result := 'x';
end;
```

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Have you tried setting "use debug DCUs" in tthe Debugging section of Delphi's Project Options pop-up, under Delphi Compiler | Compiling?

Comment: @MartynA Thet is the option what I  was looking for. Please convert your comment to an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you should set the checkbox "use debug DCUs" on the RHS of the Debugging section of Delphi's Project Options pop-up, under Delphi Compiler | Compiling.